# when redirecting to a page that was initially in edit mode to a readonly mode the gridview doesnot appear but text box appears in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have 2 pages (Trial.aspx and TestCallBack.aspx). Trail.aspx will first be editable mode. Now from TestCallBack.aspx i will redirect back to Trail.aspx but all the controls should be read only format. I have given the source code details below. Only the textbox of trial.aspx is readonly, the gridview is not seen at all.

### Trial.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Trial.aspx.cs" Inherits="PTest.Trial" EnableEventValidation ="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>  
<asp:TextBox ID="txtVisitor" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
       <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty ="true" Visible ="true">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 1">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 2">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 3">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Trial.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;


namespace PTest
{
    public partial class Trial : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private void SetInitialRow()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow dr = null;
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string)));
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
            dr["Column1"] = string.Empty;
            dr["Column2"] = string.Empty;
            dr["Column3"] = string.Empty;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            //Store the DataTable in ViewState
            ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

            Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
            Gridview1.DataBind();
        }
        private void AddNewRowToGrid()
        {
            int rowIndex = 0;

            if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
            {
                DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
                DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
                if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        //extract the TextBox values
                        TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtDate");
                        TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                        TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");

                        drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                        drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;

                        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column1"] = box1.Text;
                        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column2"] = box2.Text;
                        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column3"] = box3.Text;

                        rowIndex++;
                    }
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                    Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                    Gridview1.DataBind();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("ViewState is null");
            }

            //Set Previous Data on Postbacks
            SetPreviousData();
        }
        private void SetPreviousData()
        {
            int rowIndex = 0;
            if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
            {
                DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtDate");
                        TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                        TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");

                        box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString();
                        box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString();
                        box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString();

                        rowIndex++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                string name = Request.QueryString["value"];
                if (name == "true")
                {
                hidecontrols();
                }
                else 
                {

                SetInitialRow();
                }
            }
        }
        protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddNewRowToGrid();
        }
        protected void hidecontrols()
        {
            foreach (Control c in Page.Controls)
            {
                if (c is GridView)
                    ((GridView)(c)).Enabled = false;
                foreach (Control ctrl in c.Controls)
                {
                    if (ctrl is TextBox)
                    {
                        ((TextBox)(ctrl)).Enabled = false;
                    }
                    else if (ctrl in GridView)
                    {
                      ((GridView)(ctrl).Enabled =false;
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

### TestCallBack.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestCallBack.aspx.cs" Inherits="PTest.TestCallBack" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### TestCallBack.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace PTest
{
    public partial class TestCallBack : System.Web.UI.Page
    {


        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Trial.aspx?value=true");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your problem that the grid isn't showing when you come back to trial.aspx from testcallback.aspx? - sorry, hard to understand what your actual question is..

Comment: yes the grid isnt showing up.... atleast the layout though not the data..

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comment it would appear your problem is here:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            string name = Request.QueryString["value"];
            if (name == "true")
            {
            hidecontrols();
            }
            else 
            {

            SetInitialRow();
            }
        }
```

You're essentially saying If this page isn't a `postback` then perform this `IF` statement - and then in the `IF` statement you're saying IF there is a qstring value hide controls. Since you are redirecting back to this page it will not be a postback, and since you will have a qstring `value` it will hide the controls.

Perhaps try something like this:

```
 SetInitialRow();
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {

            string name = Request.QueryString["value"];
            if (name == "true")
            {
              GridView1.ShowFooter = false;
            }
            else 
            {
             GridView1.ShowFooter = true;
            }
        }
```

Not sure if this is what you're actually after, though the problem is with your if-else in your page load. Perhaps if you update your Q with the actual flow you're after; it would help us help you more.

Comment: Darren, i ll explain this here. I have 2 aspx pages. In one page i have a textbox and a gridview. In the other page i have a button. Onclick of the button it should redirect me to the first page but the textbox and the gridview should have the propery enabled set to false. But unfortunately, the textbox works fine as read only but the gridview doesnt even appear due to some reason.

Comment: It doesn't appear because you don't tell it to. You are not hitting `SetInitialRow();` in your code - your code says "If value = true then hidecontrols, if it doesn't = true then setInitialRow" - since value DOES = true you need to move SetInitialRow into that part of the If statement

Comment: setinitialrow() will only create a new datagrid right?? I want the data of the datagrid to be present in the readonly mode that is it should be non editable.

Comment: You still need to bind the grid to see ANY data - and you're not calling any code to do so. I have edited my answer - see the code at the bottom. First call SetInitialRow - before any other code, to bind the grid. Then ShowFooter = true or false depending on the condition. Hope this helps.

Comment: but this is making the trial.aspx as editable mode not a readonly mode :(

Comment: protected void hidecontrols()
        {
            foreach (Control c in Page.Controls)
            {
                
                foreach (Control ctrl in c.Controls)
                {
                    if (ctrl is TextBox)
                    {
                        ((TextBox)(ctrl)).Enabled = false;
                    }
                    if (c is GridView)
                    {
                        ((GridView)(c)).Enabled = false;
                    }
                    

                }
            }
Is this correct??

Comment: That will only look at direct children of the page - it will not loop through controls of children, such as the gridview. you would need to perform a Recursive Loop - see my answer here for one of those- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915169/saving-values-of-textbox-in-a-loop-asp-net-web-page/13916241#13916241